# Probability of having a sister

Tags: probability

I stumbled across this interview question which has many wrong answers posted. How can this question be answered?

Assume the distribution of children per family is as given in the table below:

| # children | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | >=5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p | 0.3 | 0.25 | 0.2 | 0.15 | 0.1 | 0 |

Consider a random girl in the population of children. What is the probability that she has a sister?

Comment: What is the distribution of males/females?

Comment: @user2974951 More information is not given.

Comment: obviously a good assumption is 0.5

Comment: I get the probability to be =0.5916667=71/120 (with p=0.5 for girls/boys). @user2974951, I first calculated it to be = .44375, but by simulation I found an error in my calculation - how did you get your result?

Comment: The answer depends on additional assumptions you need to make, including the frequencies of girls in families, potential correlations among the genders of children, and a possible association between gender and family size (which I believe occurred in 20th century China, for instance). @Pascal 0.5 is a strange assumption, because it would imply a preponderance of boys in families.

Comment: Well, ChatGPT 3.5 says (incorrectly): "To calculate the probability that a random girl has a sister, you need to consider the scenarios where there are at least two girls in the family (sisters).

For families with 2 girls (0.25 probability), the random girl has a sister.
For families with 3 or more girls (0.15 + 0.1 probability), the random girl also has a sister.
Add up these probabilities: 0.25 + 0.15 + 0.1 = 0.5.

So, the probability that a random girl has a sister is 0.5 or 50%." Does anyone have access to 4.0 to see what it produces?

Comment: @whuber it is a little fun math riddle and not really about estimating the probability in the real world.

Comment: @Pascallv YMMV, but in my experience that approach won't get you past the interview process.

Answer (score 8):

Assume that a randomly picked child is a girl with probability 0.5. Assume also, that girl and boy births within a family are independent.

Let $p_k$ be the probability that a randomly chosen *family* has $k$ children - these are the probabilities given in the table ($k=0,1,2,3,4$).

Now if you randomly pick a kid, you are more likely to pick one from a large family than one from a small family: for example, if there are two families with one kid each, and one family with three, you have five in all of which 60% are from the family of three. In general, you have to weight the probabilities with the number of kids in that family. This relates to [sampling with probability proportional to size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-proportional-to-size_sampling) - here we sample families proportional to the number of children.

Let $q_k$ be that probability, then
$$
  q_k = \frac{k\cdot p_k}{\sum_{\ell=1}^4 \ell\cdot p_\ell}=\frac{k \cdot p_k}{1\cdot0.25+2\cdot 0.2+3\cdot0.15+4\cdot0.1} = \frac{k \cdot p_k}{1.5}.
$$
The probability that a randomly chosen child from a family of $k$ children has a sister is equal to the probability that not all siblings are boys, thus
$$
 P(\text{kid has a sister}\mid\text{kid is from family of $k$}) =: s_k = 1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}.
$$
The probability that a randomly chosen kid has a sister, is then
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(\text{kid has a sister})&=\sum_{k=1}^4 P(\text{kid is from family of $k$ and 
has a sister})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^4  P(\text{kid has a sister}\mid\text{kid is from family of $k$})\cdot P(\text{kid is from family of $k$})\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^4 s_k q_k \\
&= 0\cdot \frac{1\cdot p_1}{1.5} +  \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2 \cdot p_2}{1.5}
+ \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{3\cdot p_3}{1.5}+ \frac{7}{8}\cdot\frac{4\cdot p_4}{1.5}
\\&= \frac{71}{120}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally, it does not matter if you ask for the probability that a randomly chosen kid has a sister, or for the probability that a randomly chosen girl has a sister. The probabilities of having sisters are equal for girls and boys -- this was an assumption I made in the start, namely that girl and boy births are independent. Some reproduction biologists may argue against this assumption, but then we would need more information than just the probabilities $p_k$.

---

Here is R code for a **simulation** of the number of sisters of a randomly chosen girl:

```r
set.seed(42)
# given probabilities
pk <- c(.3, .25, .2, .15, .1)
Nfamilies <- 100000
# number of kids in family
Nkids <- sample(nc, Nfamilies, replace = TRUE, prob = pk)
# number of girls in family
Ngirls <- rbinom(Nfamilies, Nkids, 0.5)
# vector that contains all sister numbers for all girls in the population.
# note that we need to replicate the girls as many times as there are
# girls in the family before we randomly choose a girl.
Sisters <- rep(Ngirls-1, Ngirls)
# probability of having at least one sister
mean(Sisters > 0)

## [1] 0.5912989
```

Comment: can you develop how you found the following relationship: $$
  q_k = \frac{k\cdot p_k}{\sum_{\ell=1}^4 \ell\cdot p_\ell}=\frac{k \cdot p_k}{1\cdot0.25+2\cdot 0.2+3\cdot0.15+4\cdot0.1} = \frac{k \cdot p_k}{1.5}.
$$,
it is probably easy but I do not see it ^^´.

Comment: Yes, sure. I will edit.

Comment: @lulufofo, is it clearer now? This is a known fallacy in survey sampling: the big families (or other groups) are overrepresented when you pick that random girl or guy in the street. The phenomenon relates to [sampling with proportional to size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-proportional-to-size_sampling) - here we sample families proportional to the number of children.

Comment: Yes it is clearer, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(C)$ denote the probability that a randomly selected child comes from a family of $C$ children.  Then we have $$F(C)=\frac{C\cdot p(C)}{\sum_C C\cdot p(C)} = \frac{ C\cdot p(C)}{1.5}\text{,}$$ where $p$ is the given density function. Note that $F(C)$ is nonzero only for $1\leq C\leq 4$.

Next we want to find the probability $G(C)$ that a randomly chosen child from a family of $C\geq 1$ children is a girl with a sister.  This is given by $$G(C)=q\cdot(1- (1-q)^{C-1})\text{,}$$ where $q$ is the probability that a child is born a girl.

The probability $S$ that a randomly chosen child is a girl with a sister then becomes
\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_C F(C)\cdot G(C) \\ &= \frac{1}{6}\cdot 0 + \frac{4}{15}q^2 +\frac{3}{10} q(1-(1-q)^2)+\frac{4}{15} q(1-(1-q)^3) \\ &= \frac{5}{3}q^2-\frac{11}{10}q^3+\frac{4}{15}q^4\text{.}\\
\end{align*}

The probability we seek is the conditional probability that a child is a girl with a sister, conditioned on the child being a girl in the first place, which is given by $$\frac{S}{q}= \frac{5}{3}q-\frac{11}{10}q^2+\frac{4}{15}q^3\text{.}$$  Note that in the case that $q=\frac{1}{2}$, this reduces to $\frac{71}{120}$.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

The answer is: $$\frac{71}{120} \approx 59.17\%$$

---

#### Better tables

You have been provided with a table that gives the probability that a random **family** has $k$ **children**, for all values of $k$:

| $k$ | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | >=5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P(\text{random family has }k\text{ children})$ | $3/10$ | $1/4$ | $1/5$ | $3/20$ | $1/10$ | 0 |

Let's transform this table, to build a new table which is more directly useful for the question.

First let us build a table that gives the probability that a random family has $j$ **daughters**:

| $j$ | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | >=5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P(\text{random family has }j\text{ daughters})$ | $1/2$ | $49/160$ | $23/160$ | $7/160$ | $1/160$ | 0 |

Then let us build a table that gives the probability that a random **individual girl** belongs to a family which has $j$ daughters:

| $j$ | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | >=5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $P(\text{random girl belongs to family with }j\text{ daughters})$ | 0 | $49/120$ | $23/60$ | $7/40$ | $1/30$ | 0 |

Finally, the probability that a random individual girl has at least one sister is equal to the probability that this random individual girl belongs to a family of at least 2 daughters:

\begin{align*}P \left( \text{girl has a sister} \right) & = \sum_{j\geq 2}P \left( \text{girl belongs to family with }j \text{ daughters} \right) \\
 & = \frac{23}{60} + \frac{7}{40} + \frac{1}{30} + 0 \\
 & = \frac{71}{120} \\
 & \approx 59.17\% \\
\end{align*}

---

#### Formulae used to compile the tables

The second table has been compiled from the first table by summing over $k$ the probabilities that a family of $k$ children has $j$ daughters:
\begin{align*}P \left( j \text{ daughters} \right) & = \sum_{k} P \left( j \text{ daughters}  \,|\, k \text{ children} \right)P \left( k \text{ children} \right) \\
 & = \sum_{k}\binom{k}{j}\frac{1}{2^k}P \left( k \text{ children} \right) \\
\end{align*}

(If the probability that a child is born a girl is not $\frac{1}{2}$, you can adjust the formula above by replacing $\frac{1}{2^k}$ with $\frac{1}{\alpha^j(1-\alpha)^{k-j}}$ for some $\alpha$.)

The third table has been compiled from the second table using formula:
$$P \left( \text{girl belongs to family with }j \text{ daughters} \right) = \frac{j \times P (\text{family has }j\text{ daughters})}{\sum_{k} k \times P (\text{family has }k\text{ daughters})}$$

---

#### Python code

Here is code in python to build the tables using these formula:

```
from fractions import Fraction as F
from math import comb

famchildren = [F(3,10), F(1,4), F(1,5), F(3,20), F(1,10)]
famdaughters = [sum(comb(k,j)*F(1,2**k)*famchildren[k] for k in range(5)) for j in range(0,5)]
girldaughters = [(j * famdaughters[j] / sum(k * famdaughters[k] for k in range(5))) for j in range(5)]
hassister = sum(girldaughters[j] for j in (2,3,4))

print(hassister)
# 71/120
print(float(hassister))
# 0.5916666666666667
```

Comment: There is no "the answer."  The entire point of an interview question is to explore what information is needed to analyze and answer a relatively open-ended situation.  Unfortunately, you have only announced an answer.  I fear that might not work well in most interviews.

Comment: @whuber There is a "the answer" when the problem is completely specified. What you say is all good when the question is open-ended. In this case I don't see much that is open, unless you want to consider non-uniform distributions for *"a random girl in the population of children"*, or want a non-50% probability that a random child is a girl. Perhaps the interviewer intended to lead with this well-specified closed problem, to see if the candidate could solve it, and the next question would have been about a more open situation. Who knows.

Comment: This question is open-ended in the senses I describe in a comment to the question.  Your answer makes several implicit assumptions.  Varying those assumptions will produce different answers.